# Facebook iOS integration login window

Tags: ios, facebook

I wanna put iOS Facebook integration. So I am using new Facebook SDK and so here in this Facebook tutorial documentaion provided by this link which are as under.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

It's enough or we have to add Functionalities like HAckbook example in the git hub.
in which view we have to code.

I follow the facebook tutorial ios found the error log are as under.

> 2012-05-30 16:15:09.573 ComleX1App[6121:12203]
>   -[ComleX1AppAppDelegate_iPhone logoutButtonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc559ba0
>
> 2012-05-30 16:15:09.574
>   ComleX1App[6121:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ComleX1AppAppDelegate_iPhone
>   logoutButtonClicked]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xc559ba0'
>
> *** First throw call stack: (0x15e3022 0x1774cd6 0x15e4cbd 0x1549ed0 0x1549cb2 0x15e4e99 0x61f14e 0x61f0e6 0x6c5ade 0x6c5fa7 0x6c5266
>   0x6443c0 0x6445e6 0x62adc4 0x61e634 0x1d3def5 0x15b7195 0x151bff2
>   0x151a8da 0x1519d84 0x1519c9b 0x1d3c7d8 0x1d3c88a 0x61c626 0x21e9
>   0x2165 0x1) terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Answer (score 1):

Without actually looking at the code, it seems that the logoutButton from which you call the selector is released before it can call the actual method. Can you post some of your code to see where it fails?